# fetching single object from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to fetch a single object from the array. From the array I need to fetch the nodes object

```
print_t($request); returns the the following json
200 - stdClass Object
(
[pagename] => album_comment
[albid] => n4l5h
[alblist] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => 
                [commentuser] => 
                [id] => 0
                [Totalcount] => 1
                [nodes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => hjkjk
                                [commentuser] => hjkjk hj hkhj
                                [id] => 56
                                [nodes] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [date] => 2015-11-25T08:18:34.111Z
                                [displayDate] => Wed Nov 25 2015 13:48:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)56
                                [Like] => 0
                                [Unlike] => 0
                                [rating] => 0
                                [reportAbuse] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [getcomment] => hjkjk hj hkhj
                [username] => hjkjk
            )

    )

  )

$content_value = json_encode($request->alblist);

$content_value = [{"name":"",
                   "commentuser":"",
                   "id":0,
                   "nodes":[{"name":"bm",
                             "commentuser":"bmnbnmbn",
                             "id":79,
                             "date":"2015-11-  25T08:03:07.765Z"
                           }]
                 }]
   $content_value1 = json_encode($request);   
  $content_value1={"pagename":"album_comment","albid":"n4l5h","alblist":[{"name":"","commentuser":"","id":0,"Totalcount":1,"nodes":[{"name":"hgj","commentuser":"ghjhgj","id":52,"nodes":[],"date":"2015-11-25T08:15:57.710Z","displayDate":"Wed Nov 25 2015 13:45:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)52","Like":0,"Unlike":0,"rating":0,"reportAbuse":0}],"getcomment":"ghjhgj","username":"hgj"}]}  

 I tried to fetch as
  $var=$content_value['nodes']; //shows the error Illegal string offset 'nodes'
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: check my updated post

Comment: But after you json_encode it its not any more either PHP array or object.. If your idea is to convert it from object to array you can use json_decode(json_encode($object), TRUE);

Comment: $content_value is already in json format so you have to first decode it (use function json_decode)and it will make a simple php array and now you can fetch the keys of that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just iterate through the `stdClass`. There is no need to json encode the `$request` variable.

```
foreach($request->alblist as $list) {
    foreach($list->nodes as $node) {

        var_dump($node->name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to list $list->nodes

Comment: then remove the inner ``foreach`` and use ``var_dump($list->nodes);``

Comment: if I encoded while inserting I got [{"name":"dsf","commentuser":"dsfdsf dsf dsfdsf","id":51,"date":"2015-11-25T09:07:52.314Z","displayDate":"Wed Nov 25 2015 14:37:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)51","Like":0,"Unlike":0,"rating":0,"reportAbuse":0},{"name":"dsf","commentuser":"dsfdsf dsf dsfdsf","id":35,"date":"2015-11-25T09:07:52.382Z","displayDate":"Wed Nov 25 2015 14:37:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)35","Like":0,"Unlike":0,"rating":0,"reportAbuse":0}]

Comment: I want to display only {"name":"dsf","commentuser":"dsfdsf dsf dsfdsf","id":51,"date":"2015-11-25T09:07:52.314Z","displayDate":"Wed Nov 25 2015 14:37:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)51","Like":0,"Unlike":0,"rating":0,"reportAbuse":0},{"name":"dsf","commentu‌​ser":"dsfdsf dsf dsfdsf","id":35,"date":"2015-11-25T09:07:52.382Z","displayDate":"Wed Nov 25 2015 14:37:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)35","Like":0,"Unlike":0,"rating":0,"reportAbuse":0}

Comment: I get exact answer in  $node= json_encode(($list->nodes[0]));

Answer (score 1):

just do `$php_array = json_decode(json_encode($your_object_array));`
now you can get the key of php_array like->`$php_array['alblist'][0]['nodes'];`

Comment: I caught the error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array